# add multiple EventListeners in if statement

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Is it possible to check for multiple eventlisteners before executing af function?.

the following code is intended that, when i click a button, it then checks if the two elements are clicked on, and put in a arrow.

what Im basically trying to do is check. if (element && element 1 ) is clicked on , then it should put in an arrow(in thiscase i use a picture) between the elements. Is there a better way to do it? if yes, which way should I proceed?

```
var el = document.getElementById("elements");
var el1 = document.getElementById("elements1");

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    myFunction();
});    

function myFunction() {
    if (el.addEventListener && el1.addEventListener) {
        var arrow1 = document.getElementById("picture");
        alert("clicked"); //just to check if func is executed
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if they have been clicked on previously? As you can't click on two or more elements at exactly the same time. Or do you mean do they just have some event listener set?

Comment: after the button is clicked, it should check if the elements are clicked on Subsequently.
To be honest, im not even sure if eventlistener is the right solution for my case, that just the only thing i can think of. I basically need to link to boxes to eachother

Comment: I have to columns, with 10 boxes each. what iam trying is, to match each box, with the matching one from the other column

Comment: Of these 10 boxes...is that 5 linked pairs? `A0` linked to `A1`? Or is it to many like: `A0` linked to `[A1,B1,C1,D1,E1]`

Comment: It is many to many, a box can be linked to several boxes.  and a box can receive many arrows. ...and later on I should map it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to check if the two boxes have been clicked on previously you will need to set a flag for each. You can do this a couple ways, but one would be to set a [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in the click handler of each button. Inside each handler you can then check those data attributes.

html

```
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button><button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
```

javascript

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
btn1.addEventListener("click",checkClicks);
btn2.addEventListener("click",checkClicks);

function checkClicks(){
  this.dataset.clicked = 1;
  if(btn1.dataset.clicked == 1 && btn2.dataset.clicked == 1){
    //both were clicked do what is needed
  }
}
```

Now since you mention multiple boxes in columns and matching them a little bit more setup in the html and use of event delegation could help in keeping your code small. For instance you can again make use of [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and set an attribute to hold the id of the matching element. Then take that id to find the element and see if it has been clicked:

html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="box1" data-match="box5"></div>
      <div id="box2" data-match="box6"></div>
      <div id="box3" data-match="box7"></div>
      <div id="box4" data-match="box8"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="box5" data-match="box1"></div>
      <div id="box6" data-match="box2"></div>
      <div id="box7" data-match="box3"></div>
      <div id="box8" data-match="box4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

javascript

```
//Use event delegation so we only need a single event listener
//instead of multiple ones for each box
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  //get the box that was clicked
  var box = event.target;
  //set the clicked flag
  box.dataset.clicked = 1;

  //get the matching id for the other box from the data-match attribute
  var matchId = box.dataset.match;

  var box2 = document.getElementById(matchId);

  //don't really need the "box.dataset.clicked == 1" check
  //as we set it earlier, just have it here for clarity
  if(box.dataset.clicked == 1 && box2.dataset.clicked == 1){
    //do what needs done
  }
});
```

---

Demo

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var box = event.target;
  box.dataset.clicked = 1;

  var matchId = box.dataset.match;
  var box2 = document.getElementById(matchId);

  if (box2.dataset.clicked == 1) {
    //clear the click flags
    box.dataset.clicked = 0;
    box2.dataset.clicked = 0;
    
    //display that we have a match
    box.closest("tr").children[2].innerText = box.id + " matched to " + box2.id;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="box1" data-match="box5">box1</div>
      <div id="box2" data-match="box6">box2</div>
      <div id="box3" data-match="box7">box3</div>
      <div id="box4" data-match="box8">box4</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="box5" data-match="box1">box5</div>
      <div id="box6" data-match="box2">box6</div>
      <div id="box7" data-match="box3">box7</div>
      <div id="box8" data-match="box4">box8</div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how do I do that, without predefined data matches. ex. if I want to link box 2 to 8 & 5. and again box 4 to 6 & 8 & 5. 
im thinking of making the boxes clickable but which eventhandler/type would suit best?